# Debug ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I'm working on an ARM template containing APIs of an API Management resource, that have been generated by [Azure API Management DevOps Resource Kit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit).

The ARM template is more than 50,000 lines and when I try to deploy it, I get this error:
`InvalidTemplate - Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression ' ': expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'EndOfData'.'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.`

This error doesn't contains any information on the location of the error in my template and the file is too large to be debugged manually.

Is there a tool that could allow to debug an ARM Template with more precise information? (Especially that could gives the line on which the error occurs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the extension for visual studio code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools

It will give you Intellisense for the ARM template and maybe then you will find the error.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the azure client to **syntactically validate** the template:

```
az group deployment validate 
    --resource-group <rg-name> 
    --template-file <arm-name>
```

or if you prefer PowerShell:

```
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment
    -ResourceGroupName <rg-name>
    -TemplateFile <arm-name>
```

Also, in VSCode (or other IDEs like Rider) you can download the `ARM` plugin to easily spot errors like these.

Answer (score 1):

I found the tool provided by Microsoft itself very useful.
[arm-ttk](https://github.com/Azure/arm-ttk) is a powershell script that checks your `createUIDefinition.json` and your `mainTemplate.json`.
The only downside is that it is bases on powershell and if you are on linux you first have to install `pwsh`.
Alternatively you can use a docker container.